# Using Blob URI as url in CSS for Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html5-canvas

I need to use a URI as a URL but this isn't working in IE11. Doesn't throw any error but just isn't showing up the custom cursor.

My code is as follow:

```
      if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // If IE
            var dataURL = canvas.msToBlob();

        } else {
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
        }


        $('#canvas').css('cursor', 'url('+dataURL+') 16 16, auto');
```

Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: IE support cursor types of .cur and .ani https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358795(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

As Per MSDN reference page for the cursor property, IE supports only .cur and .ani files, so you will need to use that to get the custom cursor to work.

See documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa358795(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Damn IE... Thanks!